# Trying to use JSON_DECODE on a JSON object in PHP and it returns null

Tags: php, json, decode

Am working on a fullstack application whereby am parsing some data from the frontend to the backend via Curl. This works fine except when I json_Decode the data on the backend I keep getting a **null response**

**Curl code that is parsing data to the bakend**

```
   static function global_Curl_Med($url){

        $server =  'http://localhost/digital-apps-apis/public';

        $headers = ["Accept:application/json",
                    "Content-Type:application/json"
                    ];

        $data = [
            name => $data->name,
            phone => $data->phone,
            email => $data->email
        ]; 

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ($server.'/'.$url));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }
```

**Backend function whereby am consuming the data**

```
 public function travel_letter_email(Request $request) {
        $ch = json_decode($request->all() , true);
       dd($ch->name);
   }
```

Comment: if you pass true as second parameter json_decode returns an array. Try $ch['name']

Comment: With `true` `$ch` is __array__. __You__ can check if with `dd($ch);`.

Comment: Invalid Json `{"name": "Manttst jdjdj","phone": "2508888888888","email": "m120@yahoo.com"}`. Check json [validity](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: This JSON is not valid ..

Comment: It's not even valid PHP code.

Comment: i suppose the json as you paste is from a special debug tools ? then either you remove the second parameter of `json_decode` to use it as an object or use it as an array

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm I have edited my question of how am consuming the API,, please check it out

Comment: @u_mulder  I have edited my question of how am consuming the API,, please check it out